# is there any possibility for "if" block to go out of given choices in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, vlsi

Below is the code of VHDL which uses IF block. 
In the last "elsif", the value of "my_choice" is assigned to "ch4". Then "else" block is executed, since no condition is satisfied. But, is there any chance that "my_choice" gets some other value other than (ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4), like high impedence (or anything else)? If so, how can i avoid that? Since this assignment can change the operation of the code.

```
    entity entity_name
    port
        .....
        .....
    end entity_name;

    architecture bhvr of entity_name

    type choices is (ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4);
    signal my_choice,next_choice : choices;

    begin
        process(clk, reset)
        begin
            if reset='1' tehn
                --------reset
            else
                  my_choice<=next_choice;
            end if;
        end process;

        process(my_choice)
        begin
            if my_choice = ch1 then
                next_choice <= ch2;
            elsif my_choice = ch2 then 
                next_choice <= ch3;
            elsif my_choice = ch3 then
                next_choice <= ch4;
            else  ------------------------------------coming to ch4
                ---- task for ch4
        end process;            
    end architecture;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `my_choice` is type `choices`, which is enumerated type with values 'ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3', 'ch4', then `my_choice` will always have one of these 4 values, at least in simulation.

In hardware, the available value space depends on the implementation, for example if the values are made as one-hot or binary.  After start-up a reset is a good way to make sure that the value is well-defined to one of the 4 values, and if the circuit then adheres to the timing requirements, then the value will stay in the defined values space of the 4 values.

Comment: @Raviteja: If this answer solves your question, it is good practice to click accept ("V" mark to the left), so other users can prioritize their time.